# panda.tslib module not found

Tags: python, pandas, python-xarray

I am getting the following error while importing the 'xray' module in Anaconda Spyder (py3.7):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "~\scripts\VIC5NC_Params.py", line 13, in <module>
    import xray

  File "~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xray.py", line 2, in <module>
    from xarray import *

  File "~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xarray\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .core.dataset import Dataset

  File "~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xarray\core\dataset.py", line 16, in <module>
    from .. import conventions

  File "~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xarray\conventions.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pandas.tslib import OutOfBoundsDatetime

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas.tslib'
```

Maybe, I don't have the right pandas version installed or maybe more than one pandas version installed is creating this issue, can anyone advise if this is a panda version issue? Currently, I have pandas 1.1.1 installed and interestingly xarrays has also installed pandas 1.1.2 along with tblib.

Comment: Can you try updating `xarray`?

Comment: still getting the same error and I read on github that pandas.tslib has been deprecated and removed. Not, sure why xarray is still trying to load pandas.tslib though!